# Is "pinking" a typo or a valid alternative to "pinging" or "knocking"?

Tags: discussion, editing

I've seen several answers now that refer to "pinking" in what can only be a detonation context.  I've heard of knocking referred to as "pinging," but never "pinking."  So is this a typo that should be corrected, or is it a valid term?

Comment: The term bothers my American brain as well, but, just like putting a "u" into color to make it colour, there's no issue with it as long as it's *basically* English and people can understand what the OP means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a perfectly valid and common term.

Perhaps this is a UK v US thing.  Certainly over here, it has been called [Pinking](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&q=define+pinking+automotive&oq=define+pinking+automotive) since time immemorial.

I had always taken it to be onomatopoeic.  Pinking describes the sound much better than pinging.

Comment: How could a color describe a sound? (o;

Comment: @Paul, what makes you think it is a colour.  It is a homophone not a metaphorical synasthaesia.

Comment: @Chenmunka - But it is a color ... *Local Color* ... :D